# Installing BugZilla on Snow Leopard Server: Perl install issues

Tags: mac-osx, perl, bugzilla, osx-snow-leopard

I'm installing BugZilla on Snow Leopard Server (latest version) using [these instructions](http://wiki.springsurprise.com/2009/09/30/installing-bugzilla-on-mac-os-x-server/).  And I'm having problems installing required perl modules.

It says to run commands that look like this to install required modules:

> /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime

But when I do that, I get this:

> Can't open perl script "install-module.pl": No such file or directory.

I then found instructions [here](http://triopter.com/archive/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-4-easy-steps/) for how to use CPAN to install Perl modules.  I ran CPAN for the first time and let it auto-configure, but I hadn't installed the developer tools and thus didn't have `make`.  So I downloaded the developer tools and installed them, then re-configured CPAN (`o conf init`) and updated it (`sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::CPAN'`), which made it stop warning about the `make` issues.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577059/why-cant-my-cpan-client-from-macports-find-modulebuild) and tried installing the Build module, but it failed some tests:

> Test Summary Report
>
> t/metadata.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 53 Failed: 2)
>
> Failed tests:  28, 30
>
> Non-zero exit status: 2
>
> Files=48, Tests=1124, 79 wallclock secs ( 0.37 usr  0.22 sys + 53.68 cusr 16.23 csys = 70.50 CPU)
>
> Result: FAIL
>
> Failed 1/48 test programs. 2/1124 subtests failed.
>     LEONT/Module-Build-0.4002.tar.gz
>     ./Build test -- NOT OK
>
> //hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
>     reports LEONT/Module-Build-0.4002.tar.gz
>
> Running Build install
>     make test had returned bad status, won't install without force

I get other errors when I try to install other modules, such as:

> /usr/bin/perl Build.PL returned status 2304, won't make

What do these errors mean?  Am I missing prerequisites?  How can I get my perl modules to install correctly?

Comment: Do you have the development tools installed? This is normally done by installing Xcode or using something like fink or macports.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers - Yes, I installed Xcode partway through this process so I had Make.